# How to write code for generating and sending email in c#.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am implementing a functionality for sending email to user in asp.net c#. I did this successfully using SmtpClient and NetWork Credential. But only problem I had in implementing this thing is giving credential means password to code. So how would I implement this functionality without providing credential and how would I write a code in asp.net for generating and sending  mail which are auto generated and no-reply emails. Can anybody give some valuable suggestion here.

Comment: Probably with your keyboard. Jokes aside, this is too broad.

Comment: @DionV.: I think you skipped a step... gotta engage the brain before the keyboard becomes useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send emails without authentication on the SMTP server and you cannot authenticate without password.

If you dont want to store a bare password in your code, you can store it in an encrypted form.